# Cannot set JwtAccessTokenConverter as token enhancer in TokenEnhancerChain

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a bean defined in Security config..

```
@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
     JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
     converter.setSigningKey(signingKey);
     return converter;
}
```

And below is the code that I am using to add token enhancer in my Authorization Server config.

```
@Autowired
private JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter;

TokenEnhancerChain enhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
enhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(accessTokenConverter));
```

When I tried to build the application the following error occured.

> The method `setTokenEnhancers(List<TokenEnhancer>)` in the type
>   TokenEnhancerChain is not applicable for the arguments
>   `List<JwtAccessTokenConverter>`

Comment: For testing, instead of using the autowired instance variable as a part of the list, try creating the instance in the same class and pass that as a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by adding

```
@Autowired
private JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter;

...
TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer = accessTokenConverter; // Added this
TokenEnhancerChain enhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
enhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer)); // and add the enhancer here
```